# What should I do with the first puzzle in Folgunthur?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

There are 4 pillars. I match the pillars with the stones on the wall, but nothing happens.

I cleared the place without doing anything on that puzzle.

I read a bunch of walkthroughs and they don't mention this puzzle at all.

[image: screenshot of the puzzle at the entrance]

Comment: Just to be sure, the gate was raised when you first walked in, right?

Comment: I didn't do anything and the gate is already raised

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The first puzzle was already solved by Daynas Valen, the Dunmer who was looking to obtain the Gauldur Amulet after locating the Ivory Claw. When you first enter Folgunthur, the dungeon is clear of any obstacles or enemies up to when you find Daynas Valen's corpse, but from that point onward the tomb is completely uncharted, and you have to solve puzzles yourself.

Comment: So there is nothing to do with that puzzle. That's what I want to confirm.

Answer (score -2):

If you're talking about when you first walk in, there is a place for the ivory claw. Keep going through and clear the cave then get your new shout. After that you circle back to the beginning. You will then use the ivory claw on the wall next to the stone wall that opens (not) on the podium. Inside is an apprentice lock chest. There was only 1 gold and a potion of plentiful magic when I opened it.